# Click of an ImageView in a list item is not happening properly

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I have a ListView, which m using to display the list of questions one at a time. I have used 5 ImageView in a list item i.e. each list item ( question ) has 5 answers.
What I need, is that when I click any of the image then it should first display the black background color of the selected image for say 500 milliseconds and then it should move to next question.
Currently when I click on any list item it's straight away moving to the next question without displaying black background.

```
que.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lyot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv1"
                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="78dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/selector_iv1"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/sa" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv2"
                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="78dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/sb" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv3"
                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="78dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/sc" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv4"
                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="78dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/sd" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv5"
                            android:layout_width="75dp"
                            android:layout_height="78dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/se" />

</LinearLayout>
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/queList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
</LinearLayout>


Activity.java

public class Activity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.layout);
         ListView queList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.queList);
         refreshQuestionList();
    }
    private void refreshQuestionList()
    {
        queList.setAdapter(new quesAnsListAdapter(context));
        queList.setSelection(currentQuestionPosition);
    }
    private class quesAnsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context mContext;

        public quesAnsListAdapter(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            return 10;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return myArrayListItem;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            View row = convertView;
            if (row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.que, null);

                holder.iv1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv1);

                holder.iv2 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv2);

                holder.iv3 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv3);

                holder.iv4 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv4);

                holder.iv5 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv5);

                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            holder.que.setText("Que"+position);

            for (int i = 0; i < ansBeanList.size(); i++)
            {

                final AnsBean ab = ansBeanList.get(i);
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        holder.iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                smilyClick(position);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        holder.iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                smilyClick(position);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        holder.iv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                smilyClick(position);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        holder.iv4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                smilyClick(position);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        holder.iv5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                smilyClick(position);
                            }
                        });
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return row;
        }

        class ViewHolder
        {
            ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3, iv4, iv5;
        }
    }

    private int currentQuestionPosition=0,finalQuestionPosition=9;
    private void smilyClick(int oldQuestionPosition)
    {
            boolean answerInsertedOrUpdated = false;
            if (oldQuestionPosition < finalQuestionPosition)
                currentQuestionPosition = (oldQuestionPosition + 1);
            if (oldQuestionPosition < finalQuestionPosition)
            {
                refreshQuestionList();
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: give us some code Anuj

Answer (score 0):

When you start the app `currentQuestionPosition=0,finalQuestionPosition=9;`
in smilyClick you do `refreshQuestionList()` which is called based on the values stated before.

But this method removes the adapter and creates new, and that causes whole ListView to redraw.

Comment: Yes you are right! that's the requirement. I need to display the previous answer selected first.

Comment: Just use setSelection on ListView. By replacing adapter, you throw everything out. And you need to keep your answers somewhere, because in ListView to views get recycled a scrolling would mess with your state (button colors)

Comment: i am already doing same, but what i need the previous one should remain selected when i click the new answer and it should also display the new one selected for a while and then move to next question.

Comment: The do postDelayed action that will move you forward after some amount of time. the thing about the selection is cased by the replacing the adapter or recyclngViews. If you do not remove adapter anymore, its caused by the later.
When set the view to some color, its instantiated aganin when scrolled out of window and back. You need to keep the answer somewhere else and check that value in `getView` method on adapter